# Why does git revert delete files on my filesystem?

Tags: git

I committed a file to my local repository as a test to undo my commit I ran the command `git revert {hash}` which then logged a revert message in git's history i.e. `Revert "Commit of file 1" This reverts commit {hash}`

As soon as I ran the command `git revert` it also deleted the file from my working tree/space.

1. Why did it delete the file?
2. I attempted to recover the deleted file by running the command `git checkout {hash} -- /path/to/recovery`. It did recover the file however am unsure whether it was the way to go about it.
3. If I run the command `git status` it shows me that file 1 is being tracked but is not committed. Why is that?

Comment: You might want to specify what you expected to happen. This all sounds completely normal to me: Revert undoes a commit. If your commit was adding a file, then the file is removed.

Comment: @StevenFisher He might have been expecting `git rm` and not `rm`.

Comment: @Steven Fisher - To be honest I have no idea as I am just learning git. My expectation would have been it would have left the file on my file system alone and simply reverted the commit i.e. deleted my commit as opposed to deleting the file.

Comment: Is there an option for git revert to not touch the working copy? I don't think there is, but if there is that'd be a pretty decent answer for this.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey To clarify, `git revert` does not delete the commit. Instead, it creates another commit which deletes the file (in this case, and roughly speaking). Use `git log` to see the commits. If you want to "delete the commit", you can achieve this effect by pointing at the previous commit with `git reset HEAD^` (BTW: the old commit is actually still there, until it is garbage collected). IMHO The best way to understand git is to first understand the underlying data model, then learning the complex commands to manipulate that, secondarily e.g. http://www.sbf5.com/~cduan/technical/git/

Comment: That's a good point. Just rolling back to the previous commit will restore the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for `git reset HEAD^`. That will “undo” the last commit in the sense that your repo is now in the state it was before you ran `git commit`.

`git revert` on the other hand will undo all the **changes** in a commit. So if you revert a commit that created a file, that action is reverted -> the file is deleted.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for being a n00b but I created the file e.g. `touch filename` and then committed it. So if I revert that commit, why would it delete the file? Also what do you mean by undo all the changes? When would you use `git revert`?

Comment: 1) Because from git’s point of view *that commit* created the file. 2) You would use `git revert` if e.g. Tom made a commit “improved calculation speed with clever optimizing”, but 2 days later you realize that you program (while being faster) does not generate the right result anymore. So you want to undo everything Tom did in his optimization change. `git revert` lets you do that.

Answer (score 1):

If the revert deleted the file, it means that `{hash}` that you reverted is the same `{hash}` that added the file in the first place.  The file is not lost, you could always `git checkout {hash} {file}` or `git checkout -b tmpbranch {hash}` to get the file back.  These two commands do different things, for more information refer to git help.

The reason your file is untracked is because the checkout command you ran simply created a new file that is not yet checked in at the revision you are at.

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. I committed file one which had hash {123}. It was the only file committed. I then reverted it using the same hash. Why would it delete the file? Secondly when I did restore the file it states it is tracked but not committed.

Comment: The only reason a `git revert {hash}` would delete a file is if `{hash}` was the commit that added the file to the repository.  Are you saying this is not the case?  If so then I am confused.  Your `git checkout {hash} -- /path/to/recovery` command did not put it back into the repository yet, so this is why it remains untracked.  You could `git add /path/to/recovery`, then `git commit` to put it back, but I really do not know enough about what you are really trying to do.